# Image Load in ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, image-processing, android-asynctask

I am not very good at Android development and need some help here.

My application uses listview in which each row contains an image which is to be loaded from the server. What I want is:

1. The images should be loaded in the order of their position on the listview.
2. The images should be cached until the user closes the application.
3. Until the image is not loaded, a default image should be used.
4. All of this should be Asynchronous.

Is there a **library** which could help me with this ? 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: And you expect us to write the code?

Comment: you **Must** write code for that.

Comment: No. I am not expecting anyone to write the code. But suggest if some library already exists. Or how can I start writing the code for this. Or Anything.

Comment: Start with a tutorial on listview with image. There are hundreds of such tutorial available online. Once you implement something and have any specific problem then you can ask a question on that.

Comment: I have implemented list view with Image. 
I have also read about Picasso and Volley. Can any of them help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a very easy and straight forward tutorial for your problem.

[Using UIL Library to handle your images](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-the-universal-image-loader-library-to-handle-your-images.html)